# How do I use a web hook using Stripe and ARMember in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am working on a project with a third party website, in which I will create a membership recurrent plan, gather customer's information, store it, and charge the customer. Upon subscribing, the customer's credentials and information will be passed via an API to a third party website, where they will be able to access the service.

For the membership setup on my website, I am using ARMember, which is connected to a Stripe account. I am working with a developer for the whole API setup with the 3rd party website, but as a requirement, my developer is asking me to provide the webhooks We need a hook that can give user-object or user-signup details after the successful payment event.

Forgive me for being a newbie, as I am not a developer nor anything close to that. I have never worked with webhooks before.

In looking into ARMember's webhook documentation I found this, which I believe it is what my dev needs, [arm_payment_gateway_validation_from_setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbWdU.png), however, there are no clear instructions on what to do with this, or how to use it. I guess they assume users seeking webhooks know exactly what to do with them, which is not my case. Please help anyone! Will be so grateful!

Comment: Can you check with your developer and ask if what they need is the Stripe webhooks? If so, you can check out how to set them up here (search for 'webhook') https://www.armemberplugin.com/documents/enable-interaction-with-stripe/

Comment: Thank you so much @karbi! I have made the setup as per the documentation you shared. Waiting to hear from my developer... but this was of great help. Thank you! 

Comment: Hello, so I heard back from my developer after configuring the setup provided above. Unfortunately, that's not what he needs. He replied:

These are webhooks and they will not be used in WordPress for SSO integration. We are looking for WordPress hooks which are different from the webhooks you sent. 

I tried different WordPress hooks available in the documentation of ARMembership plugin but they are not giving expected results. What we need, is WordPress hooks which give user-signup details or user-object on successful payment completion.